# Memory address, knowing the offsets and the base address of a dll how can I obtain the memory adress to set values

Tags: c#, reverse-engineering

I have my base memory address `"GameAssembly.dll"+00DA5A84` and some offets. Adding this up I got the address I need. (The red rectangle). This one changes every time that the game is reset.

[image: Figure1]

Once I got the memory address I can do the following:

```
public void isImpostor(IntPtr addrs, int valueToWriteInMemory)
{
   using (var sharp = new MemorySharp(Process.GetProcessesByName("Among Us").FirstOrDefault()))
   {
       sharp[addrs, false].Write(valueToWriteInMemory);
   }
}

var addrs = new IntPtr(0x210A83A8);
isImpostor(addrs, 0x0);
```

nevertheless I'm not sure how I can get that memory address. Not sure how to do:

`"GameAssembly.dll" + 0x00DA5A94 + 0x28 + 0x34 + 0x0 + 0x5C` and obtain as a result `0x210A83A8`.

---

Updated:

In order to know what the AddressBase from GameAssembly.dll is I have this method.

```
public int GetModuleAddress(String pName, String dllName)
{
         Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName(pName).FirstOrDefault();
         foreach(ProcessModule pm in p.Modules) 
              if (pm.ModuleName.Equals(dllName)) 
                   return (int)pm.BaseAddress;
         return 0;
}

Console.WriteLine(GetModuleAddress("Among Us", "GameAssembly.dll");
Console.WriteLine((IntPtr)GetModuleAddress("Among Us", "GameAssembly.dll"));
```

```
Result1 (As integer): 2043150336
Result2 (After Casting to IntPtr): 2043150336 here I can do the addition I mentioned before.
```

it returns an `int` so I can't do the addition of GameAssembly.dll + 0x00DA5A94. Assuming this I cast this result to `IntPtr`.  once it was cast to IntPtr I can do this.

```
IntPtr A_ptr =(IntPtr)GetModuleAddress("Among Us", "GameAssembly.dll") + 0x00DA5A94;
```

But I got this message error:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Couldn't read 4 byte(s) from 0x5C.'
```

I tried also to cast the address to HEX, with `toString("X")` method and I got as result `79C80000` but I can't do neither `79C80000 + 0x00DA5A94`  nor `0x79C80000 + 0x00DA5A94`.

looking at values inside of variables I got this.

```
BaseAdressDLL: 2043150336
A: 0, Aptr: 2057460372 (or 0x00000000 and 0x7aa25a94 respectively)
Bptr: 92 (or 0x0000005c)
```

What I'm doing wrong? I'm also sorry for my English.

I tried using the BaseAdress that Cheat engines gives me, and it works perfectly so I assume that I don't know how to get the AdressBase properly.

```
var sharp = new MemorySharp(Process.GetProcessesByName("Among Us").FirstOrDefault());


/* This does`t work 
IntPtr GameB = (IntPtr)GetModuleAddress("Among Us", "GameAssembly.dll");
IntPtr GameAssemblyDllBaseAddress = sharp.Read<IntPtr>(GameB, false);
IntPtr A_ptr = GameAssemblyDllBaseAddress + 0x00DA5A94;
IntPtr A = sharp.Read<IntPtr>(A_ptr, false);
*/


// But this does it.
IntPtr A = (IntPtr)0x11F7FC18; // Using AddressBase directly.

// -------------
IntPtr B_ptr = A + 0x5C;
IntPtr B = sharp.Read<IntPtr>(B_ptr, false);

IntPtr C_ptr = B + 0x0;
IntPtr C = sharp.Read<IntPtr>(C_ptr, false);

IntPtr D_ptr = C + 0x34;
IntPtr D = sharp.Read<IntPtr>(D_ptr, false);

IntPtr isImpostor_ptr = D + 0x28;
// read
int isImpostor = sharp.Read<int>(isImpostor_ptr, false);
// write
sharp[isImpostor_ptr, false].Write(0x1);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How this memory address is calculated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63942375/how-this-memory-address-is-calculated)

Comment: Don't post several times the same question, please.

Comment: Yes, every time you start an executable the base address changes, you can't do anything about that, this is how the processor and therefore the operating systems work, especially in x32 protected mode and in x64. I could have helped you in DOS several years ago but for modern Windows and .NET wait for someone to answer you, improve your question with more details or add a **bounty**.

Comment: I know it changes, I'm asking how to get that new address having the base memory address and the offsets. Just like cheat engine get the new addres (the red rectangule one) how can I get it that programmatically. (Also, I wrote the post again since it got downvate and no one see it again, even if I tried to update it, and the bounty option isn't aviable again, maybe due to the downgrade?)

Comment: Is that can help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467229/get-base-address-of-process & https://www.codeproject.com/articles/716227/csharp-how-to-scan-a-process-memory

Comment: What software is that "Change Address"? Where can I download it?

Comment: @Andy it is called Cheat Engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a bunch of pointers. Lets give them names:

```
"GameAssembly.dll" + 0x00DA5A94  - pointer to A
    + 0x5C                       - A + 0x5C  - pointer to B
        + 0x0                    - B + 0x0   - pointer to C
            + 0x34               - C + 0x34  - pointer to D
                + 0x28           - D + 0x28  - pointer to int (let's call it isImpostor_ptr)
```

If you want to know the value of `isImpostor`, let's say, you need to dereference (read the value stored at the memory address) `isImpostor_ptr` :

```
isImpostor = [isImpostor_ptr]   or   isImpostor = [D + 0x28]
```

To get `D` you need to dereference `C + 0x34`  and so on and you eventually get:

```
isImpostor = [[[[["GameAssembly.dll" + 0x00DA5A94] + 0x5C] + 0x0] + 0x34] + 0x28]
```

In C#:

```
IntPtr A_ptr = GameAssemblyDllBaseAddress + 0x00DA5A94;
IntPtr A = sharp.Read<IntPtr>(A_ptr, false);
IntPtr B_ptr = A + 0x5C;
IntPtr B = sharp.Read<IntPtr>(B_ptr, false);
IntPtr C_ptr = B + 0x0;
IntPtr C = sharp.Read<IntPtr>(C_ptr, false);
IntPtr D_ptr = C + 0x34;
IntPtr D = sharp.Read<IntPtr>(D_ptr, false);
IntPtr isImpostor_ptr = D + 0x28;
// read
int isImpostor = sharp.Read<int>(isImpostor_ptr, false);
// write
sharp[isImpostor_ptr, false].Write(valueToWriteInMemory);
```

Comment: It seems like this is exactly what I was looking for. There's something I'm doing wrong because I got this message error System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Couldn't read 4 byte(s) from 0x5C.', I'm gonna update right now my post so you can see my step by step so you can tell me what I'm doing wrong. Also, thanks a lot for you reply, 'd also appreciate a lot if you could give me some advice, and resources where to learn this kind of thing from scratch. Thanks!

Comment: @Sharki _it returns an int_ Why? `ProcessModule.BaseAddress` is an `IntPtr`. Just return IntPtr. MemorySharp also has `public RemoteModule this[string moduleName]` and you can get the base address with `RemoteModule.BaseAddress`.

Comment: I'm so lost and I'm so sorry. I don't even know how to use BaseAddress() method...

Comment: @Sharki I haven't used MemorySharp but try `A_ptr = sharp["GameAssembly.dll"].BaseAddress + 0x00DA5A94;`

Comment: It works, I got the same IntPtr than using `ProcessModule.BaseAdress`, but I also got the same error message. `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Couldn't read 4 byte(s) from 0x16AB53D.'` I will update my post with the same code I'm trying. I also want to apologize for bothering you so much.

Comment: OK, nevermind, all these error messege was because I was doing `0x00DA5A94` and NOW I noticed it's `0x00DA5A84` INSTEAD. I'm so sorry, now it works perfectly... Thank you a lot. Finally, if you could advise or recommend me where to learn or what to learn about this from scratch, it would be of great help. However, thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate your advice and I will put it into practice!

Answer (score 1):

Those offsets are the addresses of variables on the stack.  Where they are positioned depends completely on the functions called before the starting point.

For example, imagine this code, in an imaginary simple 16-bit processor that uses the stack to pass all parameters:

```
void Func1()
{
    int var1 = 1;  
    Func2();
}

void Func2()
{
    int var2 = 2;
    Func3(var2);
}

void Func3(int i)
{
    int var3 = 3;
    BREAKPOINT // This is where your calculations should start
}
```

When the code hits BREAKPOINT, the stack looks like (X = base address):

```
0xX0000000 <- Return address of the next line Func1 after the call to Func2
0xX0000004 <- var1
0xX0000008 <- Return address of the next line Func2 after the call to Func3
0xX000000C <- var2
0xX0000010 <- contents of var2 as passed to Func3
```

Given that you know the base address, and you understand how to walk back up the stack, you can find the address of var1 and modify it.