# How can I get a base module address in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pywin32

I'm trying to get the base module address of a process in python. I thought this `win32process.EnumProcessModules()` might help me, but I'm not sure how to use this.

Comment: What do you mean by "base module address"?

Comment: This, but in python [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467229/get-base-address-of-process)